# What is the difference between hw:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0 and hw:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=1?

Tags: audio, sound-card, mpd

Show info on my sound card:

```
aplay -L
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
jack
    JACK Audio Connection Kit
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
mpd
sysdefault:CARD=Generic_1
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=1
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Digital
    Direct sample mixing device
hw:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=1
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Digital
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
```

I don't know what is the different between `hw:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0` and `hw:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=1`.

```
hw:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=1
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Digital
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
```

Comment: It's essential the same (sub)device as `iec958:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0`, which is the digital output (S/PDIF, or maybe HDMI/DP). Usually the HDMI/DP output(s) will exist as another card's (sub)device though.

Comment: I am not sure if the iec958 "plugin" does anything different from hw. But at least it seem to enumerate from only digital output (so `DEV=0`).

Comment: You can probably see current stream info with `watch cat /proc/asound/Generic_1/pcm1p/sub0/hw_params` when you e.g. speaker-test on either of them.